# Twitter Share Button in Bootstrap Accordion Not Displaying

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, share-button

Using Bootstrap 4.

I'd like to display a Twitter 'share' button within each accordion item when it's expanded.

I can get the button to display **outside** of the accordion, just not inside.

I think it has something to do with the `class=="collapse"` on the accordion `<div>`, because when I remove it the button displays. I have demonstrated this in my code, `class="collapse"` has been removed from one accordion item and it works.

My code is below, and a link the a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/johnny_s/cjenm4hk/).

I have commented the code showing where the button works and doesn't work.

```
<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="accordion" role="tablist">

      <!-- works here outside accordion -->
      <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?button_hashtag=share&ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" class="twitter-hashtag-button" data-show-count="false">Tweet #share</a>

      <div class="card list-view-brand">
        <div class="card-header" role="tab">
          <p title="Click to expand">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" id="#4367" href="#4367" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="4367" class="collapsed">
               item 1
            </a>
          </p>
        </div>

        <div id="4367" class="" role="tabpanel" data-parent="#accordion" style="">
          <div class="card-body">

            <ul class="list-group mb-3">
              <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
                <div>
                  <small class="text-muted">ID</small>
                  <p class="my-0">4367</p>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
                <div>
                  <small class="text-muted">Language</small>
                  <p class="my-0">fre</p>
                </div>
              </li>

              <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
                <!-- works here when class="collapse" removed from parent div -->
                <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?button_hashtag=share&ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" class="twitter-hashtag-button" data-show-count="false">Tweet #share</a>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card list-view-brand">
        <div class="card-header" role="tab">
          <p title="Click to expand">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" id="#4368" href="#4368" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="4368" class="collapsed">
              item 2
            </a>
          </p>
        </div>

        <div id="4368" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" data-parent="#accordion" style="">
          <div class="card-body">
            <ul class="list-group mb-3">
              <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
                <div>
                  <small class="text-muted">ID</small>
                  <p class="my-0">4368</p>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
                <div>
                  <small class="text-muted">Language</small>
                  <p class="my-0">ita</p>
                </div>
              </li>

              <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
                <!-- doesnt work here -->
                <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?button_hashtag=share&ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" class="twitter-hashtag-button" data-show-count="false">Tweet #share</a>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is change the class of the share link.

From `class="twitter-hashtag-button"` to `class="fa fa-twitter"`

So the code would look something like this :

```
     <!-- doesnt work here -->
            <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?button_hashtag=share&ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" class="fa fa-twitter" data-show-count="false">Tweet #share</a>
```

After doing this just style the `.fa` class like

```css
.fa {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.fa-twitter {
    background: #55ACEE;
    color: white;
}
```

The updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cjenm4hk/20/)

Comment: Thanks @Pranshu Dobhal Could you elaborate on the cause please? Also, I'm not using font-awesome.

Comment: @TheOrdinaryGeek I'm not sure why it doesn't work there.

I saw the font-awesome.css file included so I thought you might be using it. It's easier to put icons and link them this way.

Comment: OK thanks, can you update the fiddle to show your answer please? I think it might work :)